# XML: Using text of one tag within another tag in the same file

Tags: xml

Is it possible to use the text under one tag within another tag in the same XML file (by the tag name, for example, or maybe by JavaScript)?

I will be grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

You could define an ***[internal entity](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-internal-ent)*** and reuse it in multiple places in your XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE r [
   <!ENTITY ReuseMe "This text is defined in a single location.">
]>
<r>
  <here>&ReuseMe;</here>
  <there>&ReuseMe;</there>
</r>
```